# Idiom meaning let’s leave it at that

Tags: idiom-requests

In Danish there is an idiom that litterally translates *peace with that* (*fred med det*), that indicates that the speaker wishes to end a discussion. *Let’s leave it at that* has the same meaning but a different tone. Is there something closer?

Comment: The more common form of the idiom is _fred være med det_ ‘peace be with it/that’. And it doesn’t really mean that the speaker wishes to end a discussion as such; more that the speaker doesn’t view the thing talked about as important enough to warrant discussing at any length, but more as a minor side issue or detail that can be left either way without really influencing the main point. The closest match I can think of in a comparable context in English would be something like, “whatever/whichever… but, anyway”.

Comment: And of course a second, very common, usage is to indicate that some behaviour or topic doesn’t bother the speaker, at least not enough that they want to bother being bothered about it, even if it is perhaps not entirely by the book. For example, “A lot of people go skinny-dipping in the lake here at night, and _fred være med det_. But when they start doing it in the middle of the day, with families with children having picnics right on the banks, then it becomes problematic.” Can’t think of an English idiom to match that sense off the top of my head.

Comment: Are you sure it can’t be used to end a discussion (with no implication about its importance or unimportance)?

Comment: What's wrong with, 'Let's leave it at that'?

Comment: It’s not used in an “I don’t want to talk about it” kind of way, to end a discussion completely. It can be used more ‘aggressively’ in a dismissive way, but still in the sense “but that doesn’t matter, it’s unimportant; what I want to talk about is X”—more a case of ending a particular part of a discussion (seen as a digression) and steering the discussion towards what are to you more important parts.

Comment: I don’t know. Maybe I feel the Danish phrase has a slightly jocular quality, which I like.

Comment: "That's it" or "that's all?"   Or, "that's all there is to it" if you want to be more explicit.

Comment: *give it a rest*

Answer (score 1):

***Let's agree to disagree***

"The term 'agree to disagree' or 'agreeing to disagree' is a phrase in English referring to the resolution of a conflict (usually a debate or quarrel) whereby all parties tolerate but do not accept the opposing position(s). It generally occurs when all sides recognise that further conflict would be unnecessary, ineffective or otherwise undesirable. They may also remain on amicable terms while continuing to disagree about the unresolved issues."  Wikipedia

This phrase can mean anything from "I don't want to waste any more time arguing with an idiot" to "you have valid points, but I am not convinced and I like you too much to argue with you" depending on the tone of the speaker and how he/she tries to change the subject right after uttering the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

How about the informal "end of story"?

> **end of story**
>   *phrase (informal)*
>
> used to emphasise that there is nothing to add on a matter just mentioned

*Source: Google/Oxford Dictionaries*

Comment: This is more harsh and asseverative than what I seek. (I don’t want it to imply that the speaker is right.)